# Is it possible to a full system Copy and run it in Parallels?

Tags: virtualization, parallels-desktop, bootable-disk

i have Mac Server and i want to have a full copy of the System.
So i can play around and test new Software and Upgrades before i apply it to the real System.
I am using Parallels and want to create a image from the System with the Disk Utility.
But i cannot find any Tutorials to do so.

Is it even possible ?

Comment: Where did you search for tutorials on this already? parallels.com and googling for "cloning OS X for parallels vm" would probably be good places to start.

Comment: What versions of Server and/or the operating system do you have?  If they are old enough, the answers are very different.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have experience with Parallels, but if you own an external hard disk, you could clone your Mac Server to this hard disk (e.g. with Carbon Copy Cloner or also OS X Disk Utility).

Then boot from the external disk and try whatever you want to try/install - it will not affect your Mac's internal disk. So once you disconnect the external disk and boot from your internal disk again, everything will be as it was before.